# Android Material recolor EditText underline

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, styles, material-design

how can I recolor the underline of an EditText in android 5.0 (Material) ?
It is appearing gray but I want it to be blue, how can I archieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to set in your app Theme this line:

```
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#123490</item>
```

(or `colorAccent` for wider range of coloring)

more about new Material xml styles params [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html). you should also define `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark`

Comment: Another question: the underline gets thicker if it is focused. How can I disable that?

Comment: just like whole Material theme/style, so obviusly... you can use `name="colorControlActivated"` (without `android:` prefix) with [AppCompat](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) library to port (most of) material theming/styling to older devices

Answer (score 3):

To do it programmatically: 
    `editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);`

Comment: This only works until the field has been blurred from, then it reverts back to the default color.